# How to hide and show App Bar with CoordinatorLayout and LinearLayout, NOT recyclerview

Tags: android, scroll, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to use Google's new features for more natural scrolling and hideable toolbars to create an app like the Google Play Store app with an App Bar that hides on scrolling, and a Tab bar that does not hide on scrolling.

Weirdly though, all explanations and guides I can find only have recycler views for all of the tabs that do this, so

can you have the same type of App Bar hiding and showing, triggered by scrolling, but for a scrollable linear layout element?

Short version: how to make coordinatorlayout & App Bars smoothly hide when scrolling through a simple linearlayout in a Tab

Thanks!

**activity_part_three.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_white_24dp"
        android:onClick="fabAction"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.ScrollingFABBehavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**PartThreeActivity.java**

```
public class PartThreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    public AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlue);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_part_three);

        initToolbar();
        initViewPagerAndTabs();
    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
    }

    private void initViewPagerAndTabs() {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(PartThreeFragment.createInstance(20), getString(R.string.tab_1));
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(PartThreeFragment.createInstance(4), getString(R.string.tab_2));
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(HomeFragment.newInstance(), "HOME");
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    public void fabAction(View view) {
        System.out.println("allo");
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
    }

    static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragmentList.add(fragment);
            fragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pl.michalz.hideonscrollexample.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return homeFragment;
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

**PartThreeFragment.java**

```
public class PartThreeFragment extends Fragment {

    public final static String ITEMS_COUNT_KEY = "PartThreeFragment$ItemsCount";

    public static PartThreeFragment createInstance(int itemsCount) {
        PartThreeFragment partThreeFragment = new PartThreeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ITEMS_COUNT_KEY, itemsCount);
        partThreeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return partThreeFragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_part_three, container, false);
        setupRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        return recyclerView;
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(createItemList());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }

    private List<String> createItemList() {
        List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null) {
            int itemsCount = bundle.getInt(ITEMS_COUNT_KEY);
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                itemList.add("Item " + i);
            }
        }
        return itemList;
    }
}
```

**fragment_part_three.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView won't  associate with CoordinatorLayout. Use Nested Scrollview.

```
<<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    </LinearLayout>
</<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: how to back toolbar back programm?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: when I scroll RecycleView down toolbar hide (with animation). How to back toolbar programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Listview` only when **api >21** you can simulate the same hide effect of `RecyclerView`.

Try with `ListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);`